# Salesforce Data Journey Builder Decision Splits

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

Using Salesforce Data in a journey and the decision splits are not properly accepting the met criteria. Some clarifications that I think I'm missing:

In contact builder, I have connected the data that I need to filter throughout the journey through decision splits. The data extensions that I'm using are filtered DEs automated from my synced.

Am I correct in thinking that is where my contact data decision splits should be filtering? Also, if I'm looking for the most updated data, I would have to ensure my automations are running frequently?

Thank you for any insight as I try to fix my issue.

Comment: Salesforce Data works for injecting contacts on your journey based on an action on the Sales/Service Cloud (create, update). What is the frequency of the synchronization? Are you giving time to the data to get down in the synchronized data extensions and then into your filtered DEs?

Comment: Hello Rachid, 15 minutes for polling and then automations running every hour. Is there a better workaround for more immediate filtering based on updated criteria?

Comment: When configuring your Saleforce Data, you can choose the Entry Data which you can use in your decision splits. I'll post the image in a response because I can't post it here in comments.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to do real time processing of your data.

Using Salesforce Data, you can choose Entry Data fields from SalesCloud.

[image]

You can then use these fields in your Decision Splits.

[image]

Comment: Hey Rachid, thank you. I've actually never thought of that before. Is that also being updated in real-time to what's in sales cloud? (PS i upvoted you but doesn't show due to my reputation being new still).

Comment: Basically, Journey Data preserves the state of a contact's data at the moment an entry event fires. But, I did not test it in this particular case (with Salesforce Data).